# How to get array from a json formatted form in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, form-data

I am new to `SCALA` where I am going to develop an `API` with `PLAY` and `SLICK`.

I am going fetch an array (json formatted all the values are in integer) from a form via a web request like as follows:-

Request data:

```
{"ids": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

Now I would like to fetch the form array data. Therefore I have declare a Form in my controller as:-

```
case class IdsForm(ids: Array[Int])

private val idsForm: Form[IdsForm] = Form(
  mapping(
    "ids" -> ????
  )(IdsForm.apply)(IdsForm.unapply)
)
```

Now Would like to print all the elements in that array. Hence declare a function as follows:-

```
def getIds() = Action.async(parse.json) {
  implicit request => idsForm.bind(request.body).fold(
    formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(formWithErrors.toString)),
    form => {
      val ids = form.ids
      // Print all the array elements
      for ( x <- ids ) {
         println( x )
      }
      val responseBody = Json.obj(
          "status" -> 200,
          "message" -> Json.toJson("Successfully printed")
        )
      Ok(responseBody)
    }
  )
}
```

Please let me know, what to put instead of **`"ids" -> ????`** on my code. In case of single number I have putted `"id" -> number`. I don't know what to put instead of **`????`** in **`"ids" -> ????`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my code as:-

```
case class IdsForm(ids: Seq[Int])

private val idsForm: Form[IdsForm] = Form(
  mapping(
    "ids" -> seq[number]
  )(IdsForm.apply)(IdsForm.unapply)
)
```

And the function is:-

```
def getIds() = Action.async(parse.json) {
    implicit request => idsForm.bind(request.body).fold(
        formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(formWithErrors.toString)),
        form => {
          val ids = form.ids
          // Print all the array elements
          for ( x <- 0 to ids.length - 1 ) {
             println( ids(x) )
          }
          val responseBody = Json.obj(
              "status" -> 200,
              "message" -> Json.toJson("Successfully printed")
            )
          Ok(responseBody)
        }
    )
}
```

It works fine. Is it ok?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a form to submit JSON... [Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonHttp#Creating-a-new-entity-instance-in-JSON) you have example how to do it. Although, you could upload a JSON file if you want?

For example(I didn't test this), your data class:

```
case class MyData(ids: List[Int])
object MyData { implicit val myDataJsonFormat: Json.format[MyData] }
```

Your controller route:

```
def uploadJson = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  val dataResult = request.body.validate[MyData]
  dataResult.fold(
    errors => { BadRequest(........) },
    data => { 
      // do whatever with data....
      Ok(....) 
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: note that you can do `Action(parse.json[MyData])` and play will automatically validate the json. you get less control over the response that way though (parse errors get passed to the default error page and rendered as html). this can be mitigated by making your own version of `parse.json` using the `validate` method from `BodyParser` (more info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParser@validate[B](f:A=%3EEither[play.api.mvc.Result,B])(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):play.api.mvc.BodyParser[B])